How can I add vertices inside the rim so I can measure the hole here?
I need to measure how wide the hole is for a personal project. I used the solidify modifier and made it 0.3mm. Also is there anyway I can make this manifold without covering the hole?


Hello and welcome to BSE. your question is how can you add vertices. You can do that by applying the Solidify Modifier.

Is your screenshot supposed to show the correct measurements? Because if the diameter is supposed to be 0.8", then the wall thickness is much more than 0.3 mm. Did you scale the object in Object Mode without applying the scale afterwards (Ctrl+A)? If you did everything correctly, there should not be a need for measuring the width of the hole: 0.8" = 20.32 mm - 2(0.3 mm) = 19.72 mm. For getting a manifold "real" mesh, apply the Solidify modifier as @HarryMcKenzie said.
